# MKMapView: offset map to make the annotation visible

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a MapView with the supplementary view at the bottom visible all the time. Sometimes the supplementary view partially blocks the selected *MKAnnotationView*. Is there any way to move the map a bit up when the annotation is selected programmatically?

The code I'm using now as follows:

```
  mapView.selectAnnotation(selected, animated: true)
  mapView.showAnnotations([selected], animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: try to change span of region

Comment: Thanks, I've came to a working solution by adjusting the MapRegion manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code I've finished with:

```
    let coordinate = selected.coordinate
    let delta = CLLocationDegrees(0.003)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: delta, longitudeDelta: delta)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    let rect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: region)
    // Adjust padding here
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 150, right: 0)
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: insets, animated: true)



   // Convert CoordinateRegion to MapRect
  func MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region:MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
    let topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))
    let bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))

    let a = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
    let b = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)

    return MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(x:min(a.x,b.x), y:min(a.y,b.y)), size: MKMapSize(width: abs(a.x-b.x), height: abs(a.y-b.y)))
  }
```